# Angular2 - calling multiple web api restful services

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to call multiple services in my Angular2 app?

I am making the calls using Http.Get, this throws random errors stating the following:

```
Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'CustomersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
```

I can call the services fine using a tool but for some reason having multiple calls to different services causes this issues

Code:

```
 public getCustomer(customerId: number): Observable<CustomerDetailResponse>{

        // const body = JSON.stringify(customerId);
        const headers = new Headers();        
        headers.append('Authorization', 'eyJ');        

        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('customerId', customerId.toString());

       return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl, { headers:headers, search: params })
         .map((data: Response) => data.json())
         .debounceTime(1000)
         .distinctUntilChanged()
         .catch(this.handleError);  




    }



private getLookUp(lookup: string){

        const body = JSON.stringify(lookup);
        const headers = new Headers();        
        headers.append('Authorization', 'ssds');        

       return this.http.get(this.serviceUrlBase + lookup, { headers:headers })  
         .map
         (
             (data: Response) => data.json()         
         )
         .debounceTime(1000)
         .distinctUntilChanged()
         .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Comment: yes you can call a lot of services, but it's better you paste the code

Comment: Add code on how you are consuming services

Comment: @stackdave code added now

Comment: @MadhuRanjan code added now

Comment: It seems the problem is not related with AngularJS but with server side. Without the code I'm not sure what is happening, but I guess could be something related with how you are registering your dependencies with your IoC Container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the error?

It says to add a parameterless constructor to the `CustomersController` like so:

```
constructor() {}
```

Comment: Typescript syntax?